# App doesn't receive remote notification when it is not running

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, parse-platform

My app doesn't receive push notifications when it's not running.
I am trying to handle remote notification sent as JSON and update data in my app using data from given JSON.
All is going well when app is active or in background.
But when app is not running, app is processing notifications only when I open my app by tapping on notification, but not when I open app by tapping on icon.
Here is the code from appDelegate class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [Parse setApplicationId:appId
              clientKey:clKey];

   if (application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateBackground) {

     BOOL preBackgroundPush = ![application respondsToSelector:@selector(backgroundRefreshStatus)];
     BOOL oldPushHandlerOnly = ![self respondsToSelector:@selector(application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)];
     BOOL noPushPayload = ![launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
     if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
        [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
     }
   }
   [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
                                                UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
                                                UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|
                        UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability];
   NSDictionary *notificationPayload = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

   [self processPushNotification:notificationPayload foreground:YES];
   return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  TFLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken");
// Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
  PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
  [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
  [currentInstallation saveInBackground];

  TFLog(@"deviceToken: %@, currentInstallation.badge: %ld", currentInstallation.deviceToken, (long)currentInstallation.badge);

  TFLog(@"deviceToken: %@, deviceType: %@", currentInstallation.deviceToken, currentInstallation.deviceType);
  TFLog(@"installationId: %@", currentInstallation.installationId);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
  TFLog(@"didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError %@", error);
  if (error.code == 3010) {
    TFLog(@"Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.");
  } else {
    // show some alert or otherwise handle the failure to register.
    TFLog(@"application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error);
  }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
  TFLog(@"%@", userInfo);
  [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
  [self processPushNotification:userInfo foreground:YES];
  [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
  TFLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification2");
  [self processPushNotification:userInfo foreground:YES];
  [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];
}
```

As result, app is receiving remote notification in all states, excepting when it is not running.
What have I missed?

Comment: are you set background mode `remote-notification` ?

Comment: In plist file I have set "Required background mode = App downloads content in response to push notifications".

Answer (score 2):

You have missed the bit in the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4) where it says -

> If the action button is tapped (on a device running iOS), the system
>   launches the application and the application calls its delegate’s
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (if implemented); it
>   passes in the notification payload (for remote notifications) or the
>   local-notification object (for local notifications).
>
> If the application icon is tapped on a device running iOS, the
>   application calls the same method, but furnishes no information about
>   the notification

Also, this note from Apple -

> **Important:** Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not
>   guaranteed. It is not intended to deliver data to your app, only to
>   notify the user that there is new data available.

If your application is launched from the app icon rather than the notification you need to check for updated content independent of any push notification that may have been received.  This enables an application to behave differently when it opens from a notification and when it is opened from the app icon.

For example, the Facebook app opens directly to the item in the notification when launched from the notification alert but not when launched from the app icon - which is the "correct" behaviour from a user point of view.  If I interact with the notification then I am interested in its content.  If I launch the app from the icon then I just want to use the app - I can then access the notifications in the app if I want.

Comment: Thats works only if content is available on server. Thank you!

Comment: I have another one problem with remote notifications on "not running" app. When I send simple push notification (simple text) the badge on app icon is incrementing, but when I send JSON, it isn't incrementing. Where is the issue?

Comment: You need to specify the `badge` key in the aps dictionary - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1

Comment: Badge key is specified, badge on app icon doesn't incrimenting only when app is not running.

Comment: What value are you sending for Badge:?  It doesn't increment, you have to send the number that you want displayed or 0 to clear the badge

Comment: Thanks, I have resolved it. Problem was in     UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability

Answer (score 0):

**There's no way you can get the information about your push notification JSON payload when you launch the app by explicitly tapping the app icon.**

That's as per Apple's design. When you open the application from any push notification action, then you can retrieve the push notification in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` delegate method. Typically you look up for the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` key in your launchOptions dictionary.

But, when you open the app by explicitly tapping the application icon, though still the `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` delegate will be called, the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` key will return `nil`.

Comment: what is  the solution if user not tap notification payload. If user directly open app by clicking app icon UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey is returning nil